# How do I make Inno Setup quit if the system does not meet minimum requirements?

Tags: installer, requirements

We are developing a game using Inno Setup and require a feature where the installer detects system specs (CPU, GPU, RAM, Disk Space) and automatically quits or prompts to quit if the requirements are not met.

How can we do this with Inno Setup?

Comment: Inno setup has its own tag on Stack Overflow and [an extensive set of tagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup). While this isn't necessarily off-topic herre, checking requirements isn't game-dev specific & since SO gets a lot more traffic than GD.SE, I recommend using that resource first.

Answer (score 0):

According to their FAQ entry for [conditional installs](https://jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#conditional):

> Can Inno Setup do a conditional installation - for example, proceed only if a certain registry key or file exists?
>
> Yes, through the [Pascal Scripting feature](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptintro).

Comment: This answer would be even better if it gave a hint about how to use the Pascal scripting feature to accomplish this goal - like noting functions that can be used to query the system specs, display an appropriate error message, and abort.